# How to make checkboxlist work as radiobuttonlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am developing an application which consists of two checkboxlist which displays like true or false. How to make second checkboxlist unchecked when first checkboxlist checked like radio button using javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <label>Item 1 <input type="checkbox" id="ch0" name="ch0" value="onclick="if(this.checked)document.getElementById('ch1').disabled=true; else document.getElementById('ch1').disabled = false;" /></label><br />
<label>Item 2 <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="ch1" value="onclick="if (this.checked) document.getElementById('ch0').disabled=true; else document.getElementById('ch0').disabled = false;"/></label>
```